# Finding the function of the power series $\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

> Find the sum function of the following power series $\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n}$

I actually felt like I had the right idea on this one, my solution is:

Moving one $x$ out of the sum and then differentiating we get

$$\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n}=x\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n}=2x\int\left(\sum\limits _{n=2}^{\infty}x^{2n-1}\right)dx=2x\int\left(\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}x^{2n-1}-x\right)dx$$

Taking the remaining sum, we can split it to get

$$\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}x^{2n-1}=\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\left(x^{n}+\left(-1\right)^{n-1}x^{n}\right)=\sum\limits _{n=0}^{\infty}x^{n}-\sum\limits _{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-x\right)^{n}$$

now using the geometric sum, and putting it all back, we get that

$$\begin{aligned}\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n}= & 2x\int\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1}{1+x}-x\right)dx\\
= & 2x\left(-\ln\left(1-x\right)-\ln\left(1+x\right)-\frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

But this solution is apparently wrong, and I'm not sure where my mistake is...

Comment: You have missed the factor $\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits _{n=1}^{\infty}\left(x^{n}+\left(-1\right)^{n-1}x^{n}\right)$

Comment: @r9m yep, you are right...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the Taylor series $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{n}}{n}=-\log\left(1-x\right),\,\left|x\right|<1
 $$ we get $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n}=x\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{2n}}{n}=-x\log\left(1-x^{2}\right).$$

Comment: That's a lot simpler than my way...